# Detect or split icons in a grid

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm writing a third-party tool app for a smartphone game. In this game, there is a page showing icons in a grid:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to make a feature that can detect and split out these icons.
I tried many things like [Sudoku detection](https://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-opencv-detection/), [Detecting grids in images](https://spectrum.chat/opencv/general/detecting-grids-in-images%7E763a2b69-8f63-4ce4-b142-29c2e711370e).
By following these tutorials, the best result I got is something like this:

[image]
[image]

It's not a good result and I don't know what I can do next to process it.
The reason why it's difficult I think is:

- the background color is so strong.
- the content within icons is much richer than the separator between them.
- Actually, there is no separator line, but only frames being around icons.

So is there any algorithm that can detect square vaguely? Or any other approach/suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that window holding the icons always the same size and in the same position? If so, I'd begin by cropping the image so that you have just the area of the window with the icon grid, excluding the scroll bar. Then I'd try vertical/horizontal projection to identify the vertical/horizontal gaps between the icons -- due to the gray background, there seems to be much less variation in the gaps than in the areas that contain the icons.

Comment: Because different devices have different screen sizes/aspects, the position and the size of that window will also be slightly different so I cannot hard code it. Projection is a good perspective. I've thought about it but didn't know it calls "projection".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to consider the point that the borders colour of your icons is almost white, and the icons are contained in a grid.

Hence, a proper **thresholding** will lead you into something like this:

```py
import cv2

BGR = cv2.imread('input.jpg')

Cpy = BGR.copy()

# Thresholding
Cpy[Cpy[...,0]!=Cpy[...,1]]=0
Cpy[Cpy[...,2]<200]=0

Cpy[Cpy>0]= 1
```

[image: th]

after that you need to find the **corners**:

```py
import numpy as np

rowSum = Cpy[...,0].sum(axis=0)
colSum = Cpy[...,0].sum(axis=1)

rows = np.zeros_like(Cpy)
cols = np.zeros_like(Cpy) 
mask = np.zeros_like(Cpy)

# Not sure if these values will work always
rows[:, rowSum>100] = 1
cols[colSum>200, :] = 1

mask = rows*cols

y0 = np.min(np.nonzero(mask.sum(axis=1))[0])
y1 = np.max(np.nonzero(mask.sum(axis=1))[0])

x0 = np.min(np.nonzero(mask.sum(axis=0))[0])
x1 = np.max(np.nonzero(mask.sum(axis=0))[0])

mask[y0:y1, x0:x1] = 1

mask1 = mask*rows
mask2 = mask*cols

mask = np.maximum(mask1, mask2)
```

[image: corners]

After that, you are free to use any method to detect your images as you have the corners of your icons, here I used **Morphological dilation** to process the corners, and **labeling**:

```py
SE = np.ones((16,16))
dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, SE)
dilated [...,1:3] = 0

from skimage.measure import label

labelled = label(1-dilated [...,0])
```

[image: mask]

Now you have your mask, thus you can detect your images:

```py
labelled[labelled==1] = 0
labelled[labelled >0] = 1

labelled = labelled.astype(np.uint8)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(BGR,BGR,mask = labelled)

cv2.namedWindow('Splitted Images', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Splitted Images', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: result]

Comment: It looks amazing! I will try it and report the result later